# how to merge DIVs across li elements

Tags: css, html

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <div id='div1'><div>
       <div id='div2'><div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div id='div3'><div>
       <div id='div4'><div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div id='div5'><div>
       <div id='div6'><div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Above html will design following design

```
 li li li
|__|__|__| -> odd DIVs
|__|__|__| -> even DIVs
```

I want to merge all the odd DIVs and place some text on the top of it.

```
 li li li
 |__|__|__| -> odd DIVs
 |__|__ __| -> even DIVs
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: do you feel comfortable using either some jquery, javascripit, or some outside scripiting?

Comment: why would you do this?  Why don't you tell us what you want to achieve, this seems like you are using the wrong kinds of markup.

Comment: this looks like you're trying to show some tabular data. css doesn't mean use divs for everything. use tables if your data is tabular. don't try to recreate a table structure using divs or lis for that matter

Comment: I am comfortable using jquery, javascripit, or css3.

Comment: I am comfortable using jquery, javascripit, or css3. Also I want to create tabular data - its a calendar where on top horizontal will represent date and vertical will show time. User can select one or more date for same timing. I have user li to for each column and each li holds one or more divs which shows timing. I am using jCarousel on date to move horizontal (at once only 10 dats user can see.) which require li element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
li div:last-child {
    display: inline;
}
```

Ive tested it in Firefox 5 only, and it seems to work.

See an example here http://jsfiddle.net/ffESR/